# cursor.fetchall() возвращает пустой список

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, база-данных, sqlite

имеется такой код:

```py
connection = sqlite3.connect('base.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
f = cursor.fetchall()
print(f)
```

пытаюсь достать все из переменной `cursor`, но получаю `[]`, с чем это может быть связано?

при этом в другом куске кода такой же фрагмент работает.(курсор и соединение я там закрываю, но при этом заново открываю его здесь)

Comment: `cursor.fetchall()` - возвращает записи, которые вернул запрос, отправленный на сервер при помощи `cursor.execute(sql)`... Не виже в вашем коде `cursor.execute(sql)`

Comment: @MaxU и вправду, нашел у себя в коде execute(), подскажите, а как вернуть записи без него? просто открыв базу

Comment: если хотите использовать SQL, то IMHO никак. Не забывайте, что в файле / БД может находиться множество таблиц...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вырезка из документации](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html):

> To retrieve data **after executing a SELECT statement**, you can either
>   treat the cursor as an iterator, call the cursor’s [fetchone()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) method
>   to retrieve a single matching row, or call [fetchall()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall) to get a list of
>   the matching rows.

Т.е. методы `fetchone()` и `fetchall()` позволяют забрать с сервера результат (строки) команды `SELECT ... FROM ...`, которую отправили на сервер при помощи команды:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT ... FROM ...")
```

Comment: все, я осознал свою глупость, спасибо)